# Can't reset to site definition in sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When I right click on a masterpage that the interface tells me is customized and click 'reset to site definition', a copy of the master page is created but the original page is not reset and still tells me that it is still customized.  I have a screen capture attached.

http://youtu.be/7HjVvloIbFU

Am I doing anything wrong? How can I reset to the original?  When I try to use the versioning I consistently get the 'Versions cannot be accessed at this time, because the server is busy'.  I am the only developer.

Thanks for any suggestions.